# Change author field's empty behaviour

Tags: nodes, forms

In the form to create a node, when the author field is not filled, the author is set to the anonymous user. I'd like to hide the author field when it is not empty.

Is there a Drupal workaround for that? I am really thinking into resolving this with JavaScript which I consider a desperate approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this portion of the node's display:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you could use `hook_preprocess_node()` to accomplish this in either your theme or a custom module, eg, something like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if (!$variables['node']->uid && $variables['node']->type==CT_TYPE) { // eg uid is 0 (anonymous) and this is the type of node we are looking for
    $variables['display_submitted']=FALSE;
  }

  // any other preprocessing goes here

}
```

The only difference really is if it were in a custom module, then it would apply across all themes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you've no way to find **everywhere** this info will appears, as it will depends of the modules/templates that you're using.

So you need to identify where it is displayed, and check if user id is equal to 0 ( 0 = Anonymous user).

You can do this in hook_preprocess for example, or just add a condition in your template.
Like for example the default node.tpl.php is like this:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could add this condition to hide the infos for anonymous user:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted && $uid != 0): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work on theme, and in THEME_preprocess_node "unset" author output if author is anonymous.

Comment: May you expand your answer with example code? As it is, it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Answer of @Jimajamma explains how to access preprocess node, my answer is not useful now :(